# What does stepped Ni(111) surface mean?

Tags: crystal-structure, materials

I think (111) surface refers to a flat surface of atoms that intersect with x,y,z axis at 1.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_index

Answer (score 6):

Stepped surfaces generally refer to surfaces (of a particular index) which have 'steps' like a flight of stairs. A cursory search on google images can yield some useful examples, such as this one:

[image]

As you can see from the example, a stepped surface will be a surface which includes steps which go from one layer to the next.